# kubernetes metrics server error because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: kubernetes, metrics-server

when I finish deploying the metrics-server it failed and got this error in the logs.
The Command I've used to install metrics-server

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

The error I've got;

```
scraper.go:149] "Failed to scrape node" err="Get \"https://10.0.32.99:10250/metrics/resource\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.0.32.99 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs" node="cicd-node3"
```

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per "pkpfr" mentioned in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2028 issue thread, I've set the arg `--kubelet-insecure-tls` on the metrics server container. that's fixed the issue